JSCH sftp download/inputstream issue
facing a strange issue. I am able to write in a folder in sftp server via Jsch, but not able to download/inputstream file from that folder. using generic code only. the request keeps on hanging and neither the file gets downloaded or inputstreamed. not getting any exception logged.
could anybody help in.
            session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);;
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.connect();
        //session.connect();
        //session.setTimeout();
        logger.info("session connected"+session.isConnected());
        channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
                    logger.info("channel connected"+channel.isConnected());
        ChannelSftp channelSftp = (ChannelSftp)channel;
        logger.info("after typecast");
        //channelSftp.connect();
        logger.info("after channelsftp connect");
        logger.info("channelsftpp connected"+channelSftp.isConnected());
        channelSftp.put("C:/Users/Downloads/abc.pdf", "/faresheet/abc.pdf");
        logger.info("after writing");
        logger.info("home"+channelSftp.getHome()+"pwddd"+channelSftp.pwd());
        channelSftp.cd("faresheet");
        logger.info("home:::"+channelSftp.getHome()+"pwddd:::"+channelSftp.pwd());
        Vector filelist = channelSftp.ls(channelSftp.pwd());
            for(int i=0; i<filelist.size();i++){
               logger.info(filelist.get(i).toString());
            }
        
        channelSftp.get("abc.pdf","C:/Users/Downloads/xyz.pdf" );
            channelSftp.get("abc.pdf" );

channelsftp.put is working but not channelsftp.get

Did you try using absolute path, to match the working put code? + Does the same (put+get) work in sftp commandline using the same credentials from the same local machine?
